# Package 'apr-1', required by 'virtual:world', not found

Tags: c++, vcpkg, apr

I just installed vcpkg and installed spdlog through it, and encountered this error:

```
-- Checking for module 'apr-1'
--   Package 'apr-1', required by 'virtual:world', not found
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  APR_INCLUDE_DIR (missing: APR_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  thirdpart/logging-log4cxx/src/cmake/FindAPR.cmake:83 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  thirdpart/logging-log4cxx/CMakeLists.txt:50 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/dbn/work/seal/CMakeFiles/CmakeOutput.log".
```

I thought the problem was that I missed the APR lib, but when I installed APR, it still produced the same error.

Then i try to delete a log4cxx lib , i get this error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package): Could not find a 
package configuration file provided by "spdlog" with any of the
following names: spdlogConfig.cmake spdlog-config.cmake Add the 
installation prefix of "spdlog" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "spdlog_DIR" 
to a directory containing one of the above files. If "spdlog" provides a 
separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

But I actually install spdlog ,and I check the dir found the spdlog lib exactly in it .

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: If you have additional information, please add it to the question via an edit; don't post it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by `sudo yum install  spdlog-devel`
The proble is that vcpkg install lib but miss some dependency?
here is the reference https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/issues/1167